# Upgrading from java 10 to java 11 and gradle 4.10 to gradle. 5.2: "Variable not initialized in the default constructor"

Tags: java, gradle, lombok, java-11, java-10

I have a simple object:

```
@Value
@Builder
public class User implements Serializable {
    private final String userId;
    private final String email;
    private final String name;
}
```

No magic here except the fact that im using `Lombok 1.18.2` here for the `@Value` and `@Builder` Annotations. All was working fine with Java 10 and Gradle 4.10. Now I upgraded to Java 11 and Gradle 5.2 and suddenly I get:

```
> Task :application:compileJava
/src/application/src/main/java/com/rbb/tutor/user/model/User.java:12: error: variable userId not initialized in the default constructor
    private final String userId;
                         ^
/src/application/src/main/java/com/rbb/tutor/user/model/User.java:13: error: variable email not initialized in the default constructor
    private final String email;
                         ^
/src/application/src/main/java/com/rbb/tutor/user/model/User.java:14: error: variable name not initialized in the default constructor
    private final String name;
                         ^
```

I dont really know what to do here. First I thought it is a problem with lombok but I upgraded to `1.18.6` which supports java 11. Now I have no new idea whats wrong.

Comment: Just a hint: `private final` comes already out of `@Value`, no need to add it manually on the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In gradle 5, you need to list annotation processors separately. Maybe that's the problem?

An example gradle build can be found here:

https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Answer (score 7):

[Gradle 5 release](https://gradle.org/whats-new/gradle-5/) has new `annotationProcessor()` configuration for dependencies ([lombok issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1945))

Change your `build.gradle` as follows:

```
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6")
compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6")
```

Or use recommended plugin - https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok

```
plugins {
  id "io.freefair.lombok" version "3.1.0"
}
```